# Twilio custom caller ID

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

On a ride booking app, it is required communication between driver and user.

Now the case, if user A contacts the driver via website or app, call or sms can be achieved via Twilio, we don't want to expose their contact numbers to each other.

If three users A, B and C contacts the driver and driver has no app installed, in fact the driver wants call back and sms reply. How the driver can reach users on Caller ID.

There could be large number of users and we can't buy separate twilio number for each user.

Please advise the solution.

Answer (score 0):

How many users are likely to need to contact each individual driver at any one time? Not many I wouldn't think.

Buy 10 Twilio numbers, assign them incrementally as users call/SMS their driver and save the assignment for user/driver numbers in your database.

If the driver calls/SMS a number in response query the database and route the call/SMS to the user it was assigned to when they called the driver.

Recycle the 1st assignment once the 11th user calls/SMS the driver, rinse and repeat.

Comment: There will be history list, and driver can contact again anytime in future. so Caller ID should not repeat.

Comment: You said the driver has no app installed. If the driver has an app installed then you just save the phone numbers for each user and driver in your database. Assign everyone a unique ID within the app and when driver A hits the button in the app to call user C you query the database for their phone numbers and set up the calls

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In order to maintain anonymous communications in this way you need as many numbers as the maximum number of relationships one person in your system has. The best explanation of this is in this [article on masked text messaging with Twilio](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134067-How-users-can-send-text-messages-to-each-other-over-Twilio) (though it applies to calls too).

Your comment on miknik's answer suggests you want to keep these relationships alive forever. This is not the way that most services build out this feature. They normally give a particular length to the relationship, Uber for example will recycle the phone number a number of minutes after a ride ends.

If you are looking for an easier way to manage this kind of number pooling and masking, check out [Twilio Proxy](https://www.twilio.com/proxy), it handles a lot of the logic for you. It is still in developer preview right now, but you can [apply for early access](https://www.twilio.com/proxy).